# Controller under a controller: Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two controllers:

```
AdminController
ProductController
```

`AdminController` has some functions:

```
index
create
etc
```

`ProductController` also has some functions:

```
   index
    create
    etc
```

In `admin dashboard` there is a button `Product`. When I will click it it will call ProductController index page.

Then in Product button subsection create, edit, delete etc will be available.
at last my url will be: `admin/product/create`

How is this possible? Give me idea.

Comment: completly unclear, show your routes dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Routing Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-prefixes). This way, the admin slug is always there but you can bind the rest of the actions from there. Furthermore, you can have multiple prefixes within each other if you'd like. If you are not familiar with the routes.php, I'd suggest reading through the documentation and just simply play with it a bit.